# Extra space before and after text link!! Need to remove!

Tags: php

I have a text link generated in PHP for bread crumbs, and I can't figure out how to eliminate the extra space before and after the link that is generated.  This is the LAST LINK:

Website link: [link text](http://www.myorphan.com/blog/?m=201011)

```
 <div id="crumbs">
 <a class="crumbs" href="http://www.myorphan.com/index.htm">HOME</a>//<a class="crumbs"
 href="http://www.myorphan.com/blog/">BLOG</a>//<a  class="crumbs caps"><?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __('Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), get_the_date()); ?>
 <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
 <?php printf(__('Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), get_the_date('F Y')); ?>
 <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __('Yearly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), get_the_date('Y')); ?>
 <?php else : ?>
 <?php _e('Blog Archives', 'twentyten'); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </a>//</div>
```

Comment: are u referring to the whitespaces before and after <a class="crumbs caps">...</a>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`trim($mystring)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: Where would you place it in the script?

Comment: @Erik Where you print the string that needs trimmed. in your case something like `printf(trim($stuff))`

Comment: I'm getting errors:  <?php printf(trim($stuff))('Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), get_the_date('F Y')); ?>

Comment: `<?php printf(('Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), trim(get_the_date('F Y'))); ?>`, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is the blind way of doing it, but try this:

```
 <div id="crumbs">
 <a class="crumbs" href="http://www.myorphan.com/index.htm">HOME</a>//<a class="crumbs"
 href="http://www.myorphan.com/blog/">BLOG</a>//<a  class="crumbs caps"><?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __('Daily Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), trim(get_the_date())); ?>
 <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
 <?php printf(__('Monthly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), trim(get_the_date('F Y'))); ?>
 <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __('Yearly Archives: <span>%s</span>', 'twentyten'), trim(get_the_date('Y'))); ?>
 <?php else : ?>
 <?php _e('Blog Archives', 'twentyten'); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </a>//</div>
```